# Partial response from one class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, partial-response

I'm creating API and need to give functionality like partial response. I know that in partial response, client/user need to pass the require parameter in controller method. But my case is little bit different. I need to create partial response based on the parameter name called `package`.

For example,

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class Class1
{
    [DataMember]
    public double? prop1 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string prop2 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime? prop3 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double? prop4 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double? prop5 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double? prop6 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double? prop7 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double? prop8  { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double? prop9  { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double? prop10  { get; set; }
}
```

So, above `Class1` is my base class which is called `premium` `package`. Now for `Gold` `package` I want few property from `Class1` like `prop1` to `prop4`. So my code would be something like this.

```
switch (`package`)  
{  
   case "Premium":  
      Fill the all properties of class1 
   break;  
   case "Gold":  
      Fill the few properties of class1  
   break;  
   case "Silver":  
         Fill the few properties of class2
   break;  
   default:  
      //TODO
   break;  
}
```

So based on the `packages`, I want to return my response. But in response I want to add only those class property which is included in `package`. So is there any way to dynamically ignore the class property based on condition?

Even `Ignoremember` and `JSONIgnore` will solved my problem. But for that I need to create different class for different `package`s, that I don't want to do that.

`Null` value is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

There's no true dynamic way to handle this, though you have a couple of options.

1. You can rely on JSON.NET's `NullValueHandling` and `DefaultValueHandling`. You can add something like the following attribute to your class properties:

   ```
   [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
   ```

   Then, you can conditionally only set the properties you want set. Anything that has a null or default value will be removed from the JSON response.
2. You can utilize anonymous objects. Anonymous objects can be composed at a whim and the JSON serializer can still create a proper JSON response from them. So you can conditionally do something like:

   ```
   return Ok(new
   {
       Prop1 = something.SomeValue,
       Prop2 = something.SomeOtherValue,
       // etc.
   });
   ```

   That effectively allows you to create whatever response you like.